# the max of four random variables that are greater than 4.5?

Tags: probability

I am currently studying for a final I have really two questions.

If I have four **independent** random variables A,B,C,D, while A *continuous* exponential(mean=4), B is *discrete* uniform(1,6), C is *continuous* normal(3.5, 1), and D is *discrete* binomial(n=5, p=.90 or 90%). What is the probability that their max is >= 4.5? basically compute Pr(max(A,B,C,D >= 4.5)

My first question is how do I construct the joint density function for these random variables. I know how to do it when the r.v.'s are all continuous, but here I have 2 continuous and 2 discrete r.v. I don't know how to construct a joint density of **all** four of these variables. Also my second question is I am supposed to find the probability **without** knowing (memorizing the formula) the P.D.F of the normal.

Comment: $P(\max>4.5)=1-P(all\le 4.5)=1-\prod_{i=1}^4 P(X_i\le 4.5)$. As for your second question, remember 68-95-99.7 rule - which are probabilities for the normal to be within 1-2-3 deviations from the mean. Hence $P(N(3.5,1)\le 4.5)\approx 0.68+0.32/2\approx 0.84$.

Comment: Memorising the pdf of a normal distribution will not help much.  Instead you need to be able to lookup $\Phi(1)$ from the CDF of a normal distribution.

Comment: Ok thank you I know how to look up the z-score. I was just thinking that I had to have four density functions. Now I know that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to construct the joint density. All you need to do is note that $P(max(A, B, C, D) < 4.5) = P((A < 4.5) \wedge (B < 4.5) \wedge (C < 4.5) \wedge (D < 4.5))$, i.e. the space in which the maximum of all four is less than a certain value is the space in which all four of the variables are less than that value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't construct the joint density, because doesn't exist(exist if the random variable is absolute continuous).

Note that, because are independent, $P(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d)=P(A=a).P(B=b).P(C=c).P(D=d)$ and you can calculate this four probabilities